# how to make T4 text template database driven

Tags: c#, database, code-generation, t4

I am experimenting with code generation atm, I've writen a small template that does what I need it to do, but I need to hardcode the properties myself, I want to extract class and property names from a database where the tables are the classes and index fields are the properties. Idea is to write a filter class based on table indexes. The code I have now assumes that I have 1 table and 3 fields to use as filter criteria.
Currently don't have any code to generate the compiled version as VS does this internally.
Here is what I have so far:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="namespacename" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="filterobjectname" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="property1" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="property2" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="property3" type="System.String" #>

<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using AzzWork.Business;
using Ventura.Business.Entities;
<# string _namespacename; if(this.namespacename==null){_namespacename = "Ventura.Business";}else{_namespacename = this.namespacename;} #>
<# string _classname; if(this.filterobjectname==null){_classname = "BusinessObject";}else{_classname = this.filterobjectname;}#>
<# string _property1; if(this.property1==null){_property1 = "LastName";}else{_property1 = property1;}#>
<# string _property1c = _property1.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + _property1.Substring(1);#>
<# string _property2; if(this.property2==null){_property2 = "Email";}else{_property2 = property2;}#>
<# string _property2c = _property2.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + _property2.Substring(1);#>
<# string _property3; if(this.property3==null){_property3 = "FirstName";}else{_property3 = property3;}#>
<# string _property3c = _property3.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + _property3.Substring(1);#>
<# string seperator1; if((_property1!=null && _property2!=null) || (_property1!=null && _property2==null && _property3!=null)){seperator1=", ";}else{seperator1="";}#>
<# string seperator2; if(_property2!=null && _property3!=null){seperator2=", ";}else{seperator2="";} #>
namespace <#= _namespacename #>
{
    public static class <#= _classname #>FilterFactory{
        internal static AzzFilterCollection<<#= _classname #>> GetFilterFor<#= _classname #>(<#if(_property1!=null){#>string <#=_property1c #>Part<#}#><#=seperator1#><#if(_property2!=null){#>string <#=_property2c #>Part<#}#><#=seperator2#><#if(_property3!=null){#>string <#=_property3c #>Part<#}#>)
        => new AzzFilterCollection<<#=_classname#>>()
<#if(_property1!=null){ #>
            .AddFilterFor<#= _property1 #>(<#=_property1c #>Part)
<#}#>
<#if(_property2!=null){ #>
            .AddFilterFor<#= _property2 #>(<#=_property2c #>Part)
<#}#>
<#if(_property3!=null){ #>
            .AddFilterFor<#= _property3 #>(<#=_property3c #>Part)<#}#>;
        <#if (_property1!=null){#>
internal static AzzFilterCollection<<#=_classname #>> AddFilterFor<#= _property1 #>(this AzzFilterCollection<<#= _classname#>> filterCollection, string <#= _property1c #>Part)
        {
            if (<#= _property1c #>Part == null)
                return filterCollection;
            var filter = new AzzFilter<<#=_classname#>>(<#=_classname#>.ColumnNames.<#=_property1#>, <#=_property1c#>Part);
            return filterCollection.AddFilter(filter);
        }
        <#}#>
<#if (_property2!=null){#>internal static AzzFilterCollection<<#=_classname #>> AddFilterFor<#= _property2 #>(this AzzFilterCollection<<#= _classname#>> filterCollection, string <#= _property2c #>Part)
        {
            if (<#= _property2c #>Part == null)
                return filterCollection;
            var filter = new AzzFilter<<#=_classname#>>(<#=_classname#>.ColumnNames.<#=_property2#>, <#=_property2c#>Part);
            return filterCollection.AddFilter(filter);
        }
        <#}#>
<#if (_property3!=null){#>
internal static AzzFilterCollection<<#=_classname #>> AddFilterFor<#= _property3 #>(this AzzFilterCollection<<#= _classname#>> filterCollection, string <#= _property3c #>Part)
        {
            if (<#= _property3c #>Part == null)
                return filterCollection;
            var filter = new AzzFilter<<#=_classname#>>(<#=_classname#>.ColumnNames.<#=_property3#>, <#=_property3c#>Part);
            return filterCollection.AddFilter(filter);
        }
        <#}#>
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the thing you have trouble with? Since you can run any C# code inside the T4 generation, you can also run code that goes off and queries a database for metadata (although, fair warning, this isn't going to regenerate itself if your database changes, and integrating it in an automated build has its own problems). Simply write the code to output C# as if you weren't in a T4 template, except that instead of writing `Console.WriteLine` you use `<# #>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking at something for SQL.

Does this helps you?

[This](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=t4sql), [This (same)](https://github.com/DataBooster/T4SQL),

Also [this](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/How-Do-I-With-T4-Editor-Text-Templates.html)

Comment: http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/How-Do-I-With-T4-Editor-Text-Templates.html is just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @NicoHaegens :)